# CKEditor 4.3 clipboard options not aligned on IE

Tags: ckeditor

I'm facing an issue with CKEditor 4.3. When I right click on the text area, clipboard options are not properly aligned with IE.

[image: The issue with IE]

Comment: maybe there is a css on the page that interferes with the one from ckeditor

Comment: Which IE version you talk about? I'm guessing this is IE11 but does it have quirks mode or compatibility mode enabled? I have seen similar (only similar) results when CKEditor was working in quirks mode.

Comment: yes, this issue is on IE 11  and having css interface but after css class which one should be have change is very difficult to find and m not able to fine that with IE11 developer tool and this is working fine on chrome